# How to access a field from a ForeignKey on a Queryset in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

class Template(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(...)
    computer = models.ForeignKey(Computer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I delete a template object, from django admin, I need to make an API request, so I edited the `delete()` method. That works fine.
But this doesn't work for the multiple delete option in django admin. I already know that I have to edit the `delete_queryset()` in `admin.py`.

What I need to know is how to get the `field IP` from Computer from the queryset that the `delete_queryset()` method returns.

When I do the following in `admin.py`:

```
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def delete_queryset(self,request,queryset):
        print(queryset)
        print(queryset.values('computer'))
        ...
```

And I try to delete multiple template objects (A,B and C)
I get the following response:
`<QuerySet [<Template: A>, Template: B>, Template: C>]>`
`<QuerySet [{'computer': 22}, {'computer': 21}, {'computer': 21}]>`

22 and 21 are the `computer_id` referenced by the `ForeignKey` in `A`,`B` and `C`.

The question is, how do I access the `IP field` from those computers so that I can make the API request in the `delete_queryset()` method?

Comment: You can access it using double underscore lookup: `queryset.filter(computer__ip=<value>)`

Comment: That only filters the queryset with the IPs I put on <value>. What I need (to start with at least) is to print the IP associated with EVERY OBJECT in the queryset

Comment: Ok, then do it using the same syntax: `queryset.values('id', 'computer__ip')`, this will print you an id of a `Template` object and `ip` associated with it